# Postgresql error, "no pg_hba.conf entry"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I am a  newbie to programming. I am building a rails app and now want to push it to Heroku. I followed [Heroku's guidelines](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3) for converting my database from sqlite 3 to postresql. After doing that I get this error when I try to migrate or even check out my app on local host

"PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[local]", user "keemtaker", database "tuma_database_development", SSL off"

I checked out previous answers to this same problem but it is so confusing and overwhelming for me. It would be nice if I can get a step by step guide to solve this error. I have used PostgreSQL before with no issues. This is how my gemfile looks like

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.3.4'

gem 'figaro'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'puma'
gem 'rails', '5.1.4'
gem 'redis'
gem 'cloudinary'
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 1.2'
gem 'rails_admin', '~> 1.2'
gem 'pg'

gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'font-awesome-sass'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5.0.0'
gem 'coffee-rails'

gem 'uglifier'
gem 'webpacker'
gem 'devise'
gem 'ransack'
gem 'trix'


gem "letter_opener", group: :development


group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

group :development, :test do
  # gem 'binding_of_caller'
  # gem 'better_errors'

  gem 'pry-byebug'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end
```

In my database.yml, i have

```
    default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: tuma_database_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: tuma_database_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: tuma_database_production
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Heroku Support](https://help.heroku.com/QVRZIEAH/why-am-i-seeing-connection-errors-for-my-heroku-postgres-database-from-an-unexpected-ip-address-what-are-these-unauthorized-connection-attempts) this is not an error coming from your Rails application but from someone malicious trying to authenticate to your PostgreSQL database:

> **Issue**
>
> I'm seeing failed connection attempts in my Heroku Postgres
> logs, but I'm not creating these connections and they come from an IP
> address that I don't recognize. It looks like someone might be trying
> to hack my database:
>
> `sql_error_code = 28000 FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "122.180.247.11", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL off`
>
> Variations of the above error might include the `user` being set to
> `root`, `admin`, `test`, or other default usernames.
>
> **Resolution**
>
> These errors indicate a failed login attempt was made to
> your database, which means that the connection wasn't established.
>
> It is common to see [failed connection attempts](https://help.heroku.com/DR0TTWWD/seeing-fatal-no-pg_hba-conf-entry-errors-in-postgres) that use default
> usernames (such as `user "postgres", database "postgres"`). Being on the
> public internet means some level of unauthorized access attempts are
> possible. These are very unsophisticated attempts that usually involve
> trying combinations like `root`, `psql`, `test` and `postgres`. However,
> Heroku Postgres usernames, passwords, and database name combinations
> are randomly generated, making these generic access attempts futile.
>
> Another common cause of the `sql_error_code=28000`, particularly when it
> involves the "unsupported frontend protocol" message is the use of
> tools like `nmap`. [Read more about the "unsupported frontend protocol"
> message](https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2015/05/28/postgres-unsupported-frontend-protocol).
>
> Heroku takes security seriously and works diligently to ensure the
> safety of your data. Furthermore, trust is a core principle of
> salesforce.com and Heroku. It’s this commitment to customer privacy
> and inspiring trust that directs the decisions we make on a daily
> basis. Trust is the responsibility of each and every employee and one
> we take seriously.

Answer (score -1):

By this configuration, your app will look to a local database, which, on heroku, you don't have

But [see here the config they're advising](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-database-connection-behavior#configuring-connections-in-rails-4-1) :

1. Add the postgres add-on
2. replace your production config lines with the ones showed in the link above

When you install the add-on, heroku will add a DATABASE_URL environment variable on your project. Rails will automatically look for and pick this variable ([see here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database))

Comment: The solution did not work. The main problem is that, I cant even run rails db:migrate or even connect with my app to localhost anymore. The full error reads " FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[local]", user "keemtaker", database "postgres", SSL off" . Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "database"=>"tuma_development"}

Comment: See your logs, it says "local", which means that your database.yml production setup still looks for a local db. In other words, it's misconfigured. As said, you need to have installed the **postgres add-on installed for your heroku app**, and if you did not, remove the **<<: *default** line. It very straightforward once done, things will work. In case, once installed, double checks your app config, click "show environments variables", you'll see the DATABASE_URL entry

Comment: understand that the DATABASE_URL will completely take over, the postgres add-on will do it all, by default you don't get to name your database. I thought it was implied by reading the link i sent you, don't even keep the `database: tuma_database_production`

Comment: I also thought you'd get how your databse.yml work, meaning you can configure it fo reach environments. So please understand that you need to keep the development and test parts you had; only change production lines. Read the whole chapter I sent earlier; those things are super basic, you need to understand http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database

Comment: @HakeemBaba still not ok ?

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify the Database URL for Heroku, since you don't have access to a local database on their infrastructure. Replace your `production` section of `database.yml` with this:

```
production:
  url: <%= ENV["DATABASE_URL"] %>
  pool: 15
```

---

So your complete `database.yml` would look like this:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: tuma_database_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: tuma_database_test

production:
  <<: *default
  url: <%= ENV["DATABASE_URL"] %>
```

---

<sup>Source: [Getting started with Rails on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5#database)</sup>

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, you don't even need that url line right ?

Comment: Humm double checked and no, not required, things can remain simpler http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database `If you have an empty config/database.yml file but your ENV['DATABASE_URL'] is present, then Rails will connect to the database via your environment variable`

Comment: That's interesting, did not know that. Anyways, it's still better to be explicit in application configuration than rely on implicit configs.

Comment: Yep I think that from this statement to which i can agree (not ok to rely on implicit configs), this is a setup that have not been much advertised; but not that new (i used heroku like 2/3 years ago)

Comment: The solution did not work. The main problem is that, I cant even run rails db:migrate or even connect with my app to localhost anymore. The full error reads " FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[local]", user "keemtaker", database "postgres", SSL off" .  Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "database"=>"tuma_development"}

Comment: @HakeemBaba See updated answer. Also remember that Heroku expects the postgres database connection over SSL.